# what causes /*global module: false*/ in grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Many grunt.js-script starts with:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {
```

But what the cause of the comment in the first line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a directive for JSLint or JSHint. It tells the JSLint/JSHint parser that the identifier `module` is defined elsewhere, so it doesn't throw an error telling you that `module` is undefined. Without it, the parser will encounter the reference to `module` and think that you're trying to refer to an undefined variable.

From the [JSLint docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> JSLint also recognizes a `/*global*/` directive that can indicate to JSLint that variables used in this file were defined in other files. The directive can contain a comma separated list of names.

And the [JSHint docs](http://jshint.com/docs/):

> In addition to options, you can let JSHint know what global variables it should expect:
>
> ```
>     /*global DISQUS:true, jQuery:false */
> ```
>
> In the example above, JSHint will allow you to override `DISQUS`, but complain if you try to override `jQuery`.