# Using chrome api with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to make a simple Chrome Extension using React.  The manifest looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "New Tab",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "A minimalist replacement for Chrome's New Tab page.",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "topSites"]
}
```

I'm not sure how to actually use the Chrome topSites API in React. I've been looking at the documentation https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/topSites but it doesn't provide much insight. I'm trying to do something like this to get an array of data.

```
chrome.topSites.get(console.log)
```

However,

```
'chrome' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score 37):

You can define chrome by adding `/*global chrome*/` in the top of the file.

For Example

```
    /*global chrome*/
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
        componentWillMount() {
            chrome.storage.local.set({ 'data' : 'Your data'}, function(result) {
                console.log(" Data saved ")
            });
        }

        render() {
            return (
              <div className="App">
              </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Was struggling with this for quite some time now.

Comment: Thank you so much for help!! But I'm curious where you get the solution. The documentation? I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: I don't remember it exactly but I think I found it on some stack overflow link only. Initially I thought its a comment but I tried it randomly and then I found it working so I posted the solution for others.

Comment: @Yumin Gui
i found this SO link that maybe helpful
      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973186/what-causes-global-module-false-in-grunt-js

Answer (score 4):

So it appears putting `/*global chrome*/` on top of file works, but I would like to explain why it works -

First of all you are using React, and the eslint configuration of React is hidden internally and by default the no-undef rule is enabled, so you can not use the `undefined` variable `chrome` in order to allow this you have to tell eslint to let it allow compilation even if `chrome` is undefined.

It has nothing to do with `react` or `typescript`, its an es-lint issue.

Here I will show you an example on eslint playground -

[image]

Upon running the code above I will get that console is not defines, and the reason for that is `eslint` is unaware of `console` API

You have various options to resolve the issue -

1. You can add `browser` if you are using browser in the env, but in your case you can use `webExtensions` to true
2. you can define globals in config file, using `{"global" : {}}` as also mentioned in another answer.
3. temporarily you can do `/* global your_identifier */`

Right thing to do would be change your `env` in eslint config as follows

```json
 "env": {
        "webextensions": true
    }
```

#### For more visit

- 1 - https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef
- 2 - https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the ESLint rule [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) and then enable it again:

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
function callback(val) {
    console.log(val)
}

chrome.topSites.get(callback);
/* eslint-enable no-undef */
```

Answer (score 1):

`yarn add @types/chrome -D` or `npm install @types/chrome --save-dev`

`@types/chrome` contains type definitions for Chrome extension development (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/).

Comment: Can you add an explanation as to what's happening and why it would answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct, but they fix the issue on a per-file basis.

If you need to fix this issue once and for all, please add this to your `eslint` config:

```
module.exports = {
  ...otherConfigs,
  globals: {
    chrome: true
  }
}
```