# Cannot use the chrome.action API inside React component

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the chrome.action API to set the badge text of my Chrome extension but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setBadgeText')
```

For some reason, the API is not accessible from React. This is my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({ text: '0' });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Tabbly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Chrome extension to help you save your favourite tabs and easily access them at any time.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo.png",
    "48": "logo.png",
    "128": "logo.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Tabbly",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo.png",
      "24": "logo.png",
      "32": "logo.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [ "storage", "alarms", "notifications", "contextMenus", "search", "tabs"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://*/", "http://*/"]
}
```

I tried setting the badge text of my extension to 0 inside a useEffect in a React component but I get an undefined error.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411447/using-chrome-api-with-react-js

Comment: If this code is injected via executeScript you can't use chrome.action there. Instead use chrome.runtime.sendMessage so your extension script's onMessage calls chrome.action.

Comment: @Sagar, did not work for me. Already tried it.